# How best to replace Attribute Vector math and Attribute mix in Blender 3.0?

Tags: node-editor, vector

I understand that attribute vector and attribute mix are now 'legacy'/'deprecated' in Blender 3.

I'm trying to achieve what's shown in the attachment with alternatives, but not really sure where to look... In the interests of staying within format rules, I'm looking at how to 'replace' a node chain of; attribute vector (subtract), attribute vector (scale) both feeding 'geometry' and 'factor' pins in the attribute mix node.

Any help gratefully appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your nodes correctly, you are setting the position using some modified UV.

To get the UV, you need to add an input attribute:

[image]

To get the position you simply use the *Position* node.

Then, you use the *Vector Math* node to perform subtractions, scale or interpolate using the *Fac* value:

[image]

You can also use the *Mix RGB* node to interpolate instead of calculating with *Vector Math* nodes:

[image]